# Why does instanceof a class return false even though the constructor is in its prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, instanceof

In a NodeJS app, I am trying to check that a value passed into a function is an instance of a specific Class, however I am getting unexpected behavior using `instanceof` between modules, and when checking the equality of the Class.

#### endpoint.js

```
import SomeClass from 'utils/class';
import SomeModel from 'models/model';

const model = SomeModel.findOne({id: 'abc'});
const values = {a: 'b'};
const classInstance = new SomeClass({id: 'def'});

classInstance instanceof SomeClass //returns true
Object.getPrototypeOf(classInstance) //returns SomeClass {}

model.update(values, { a: classInstance, b: SomeClass });
```

When the classInstance is passed through to the update function, I see unexpected behavior.

Calling `Object.getPrototypeOf(a)` returns SomeClass, as does `a.constructor.name`.  However, `a instanceof SomeClass` 
returns false.

Furthermore, just checking equality between the class imported and the class passed into the function returns false.

`require.resolve('utils/class')` returns the same path for both imports.

#### models/model.js

```
import SomeClass from 'utils/class';

class Model {
  async update(values, injections) {
    const { a, b } = injections;

    // checking instance
    a.constructor.name //returns SomeClass
    Object.getPrototypeOf(a) //returns SomeClass {}
    a instanceof SomeClass; //returns false

    // checking class
    b === SomeClass; //returns false
  }
}
```

I would expect that `b === SomeClass` would return true, just like `a instanceof SomeClass` should also return true, unless I am missing something.  Thanks for any help.

#### utils/class.js

```
export default class SomeClass {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.bar = foo;
  }
}
```

Edit:  The code is being transpiled with @std/esm. 
`NODE_PATH=./src/ nodemon -r @std/esm src/server.js`

Comment: If I make an instance with `new Model` rather than `SomeModel.findOne()` I get expected results. https://jsfiddle.net/mptbhu0c/

Comment: Too much information missing. You had better provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: num8er may have it. While they both resolve to the string "SomeClass", they're probably pointing to different instances of the SomeClass model that was defined, thus they're not actually the same thing.

Comment: what's benefit to transpile almost ES-ified code? me personally don't like transpilation. Those waitings for rereading, transpiling everytime I change somethings. Latest nodejs has classes, async/awaits - other stuff is just about: `import vs require`  nothing special. So why to complicate almost complicated JS code?

Comment: Also `b === SomeClass; //returns false` shows that it's not about the instance really. The Model class is having `SomeClass` passed in as an injection, while it also imports `SomeClass` in the same file. So right now it's thinking the classes are different, thus instances would be different too.

Comment: I'm referring to the instance of the class definition. Can you post `utils/class.js`? Is https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/633 relevant?

Comment: Maybe you could check if your SomeClass is being loaded twice, the same as in the GitHub issue I linked to above.

Answer (score 2):

Is it due to the `SomeClass` instances being defined multiple times (due to transpiler, etc)? Consider this code which will return false:

```
(function() {

    class Foo {};

    class Bar {
        check(a) {
            console.log(a instanceof Foo);
        }
    };

    window.bar = new Bar();

})();

(function() {
    class Foo {};
    const foo = new Foo();
    window.bar.check(foo);
})();
```

vs Foo, Bar, etc., being defined in a global scope only 1 time (`require()` should cache these dependencies and thus you shouldn't run into this behavior):

```
class Foo {};

class Bar {
    check(a) {
        console.log(a instanceof Foo);
    }
};

const foo = new Foo();
Bar.prototype.check(foo);
```

There's an [issue](https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/633) on the std/esm project where someone's experiencing this same thing. I don't use that library, so no ideas on the specifics.

Or I could be way off.

Answer (score 2):

Charlie in the comments pointed us the right way.

https://github.com/DaveStein/esm-bug is reproducing this and I've noted it as such in the issue Charlie reported https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/633.

Comment: Glad I could help some! Best of luck.